# Vapor MySQL - not showing as an Import value

Tags: mysql, swift, vapor

This question is about the Swift Web Framework, Vapor.

I am trying to import VaporMySQL framework using Swift's Package Manager.

I already have the database running locally, the mySQL port is open & working, the mySQL database is working, the Vapor app is working [I have written several GET / POST requests that work].

But I can't Import VaporMySQL.  **This may be related to my lack of knowledge with Package.swift.**

```
    let package = Package(
    name: "HelloWorld",        
    dependencies: [
    .Package(url: "https://github.com/qutheory/vapor.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 10),
    .Package(url: "https://github.com/qutheory/cmysql.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `VaporMySQL` package comes from the `qutheory/vapor-mysql` repository.

It looks like you've mistakenly included the `libmysql` wrapper into your project which just provides a module map for MySQL's C library.

```
let package = Package(
    name: "HelloWorld",        
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/qutheory/vapor.git", majorVersion: x, minor: x),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/qutheory/vapor-mysql.git", majorVersion: x, minor: x)
    ]
)
```

Your `Package.swift` file should look like the above. The major and minor version numbers will need to be determined based on which version of Swift and Vapor you want to use.

Comment: Not sure why I can't still Import Vapor-MySQL

Comment: Latest attempt: X-CodeBeta4 & DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-07-25-a.  I created a new Vapor project. I followed your Aug-1-2016 YouTube for guidance. Success. Vapor runs & droplets served.  I can start my MySQL service & validate. But when I change my Package.swift to include vapor-mysql I get a linker error.  Note - when I ran: swift build -Xswiftc -I/usr/local/include/mysql -Xlinker -L/usr/local/lib  SUCCEEDS.  But when I just run Swift Build it FAILS with:  library not found for -lmysqlclient for architecture x86_64

Comment: You just need to link your libraries the same way you did with `swift build` for `swift package generate-xcodeproj`.

Or, if you're using the [Vapor Toolbox](https://github.com/vapor/toolbox), you can do `vapor build --mysql` and `vapor xcode --mysql`

Comment: SUCCESS  Thank you.  Vapor is beyond good.  Within my project directory, I did as you advised: `curl -sL toolbox.qutheory.io | bash` and then `vapor build --mysql`.  Finally I ran `vapor xcode --mysql` .  Then you are auto prompted to open the project in xCode.  After that, Import Vapor-MySQL is available. ✅✅✅