# Install Vapor for Swift backend development

Tags: swift, vapor

I just started swift backend development. I noticed Vapor & installed swift packange manager (Swiftenv). I follow its [instruction](https://medium.com/@timominous/basic-swift-server-setup-using-vapor-475b10e811b7#.gwn857dg2) to install Vapor CLI by :

```
wget cli.qutheory.io -O vapor
```

But constantly get error:

```
Resolving cli.qutheory.io... 138.197.255.240
Connecting to cli.qutheory.io|138.197.255.240|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-08-07 10:41:15 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Anyone faces the same problem? How to get rid of it?

**I also tried another way :**

```
curl -L cli.qutheory.io -o vapor
```

The output is:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    38  100    38    0     0     21      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    21
```

Then, I run command:

```
chmod +x vapor
```

and then:

```
sudo mv vapor /usr/local/bin
```

and then:

```
vapor self-update
```

But I get error:

```
/usr/local/bin/vapor: line 1: error:1: command not found
```

How to install vapor CLI ?

Comment: No, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vapor team just released new setup tools.  With xCode Beta 4, the following worked for me:

- Move into your project folder
- `swiftenv local DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-07-25-a`
- `curl -sL toolbox.qutheory.io | bash`
- `vapor build`
- `vapor xcode`
- Then you are auto prompted to open the project in xCode. Press `y`

You should then be able to Import Vapor and start to play.

If that does not work try, first check the Vapor status:
`curl -sL check.vapor.sh | bash`

& then follow this article [https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-build-first-swift-web-app-vapor] word for word.  You have to match his swift development snapshot version, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, do I have to use XCode 8 beta in order to work with Vapor? I have XCode 7.3 currently.

Comment: I got it working with 7.3 but I found the whole thing more stable with xCode 8.0 Beta 4.  You may want to see another SO page after you get it setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544089/vapor-mysql-not-showing-as-an-import-value